# Ec2 thrift service hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, thrift

i want to start a thrift service in EC2 and which IP should I use in my TThreadPoolServer arguments, should I use private IP or public IP ? I tried the both and non of them works when I send a request from outside Ec2 machine. I have configured the EC2 security group rules but seems its not working.

Comment: use Public IP. You need make sure you do correctly in security group to open the port to public.

Comment: I want to open the port 8890 for the Thrift service and added following Inbound rule to the security group.Custom TCP Rule
TCP
8890
0.0.0.0/0